# how to see what an object is observing in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, observer-pattern, key-value-observing

I know there is a way to see what properties are being observed on an object with observationInfo but is there a way to see what an object is set to observe?

```
[otherObject addObserver:zombie forKeyPath:@"brains" context:apocalypse]
```

Calling [otherObject observationInfo] reveals that the zombie is observing the @"brains" keypath but I would like to call [zombie observerFor] or something and see what it is set as an observer for....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. The implementation of KVO stores pointers to the observing object in the observed object (sort of, actually, it's a dynamically created subclass of the observed object). So the observing object does not maintain any reference to the objects it is observing. The Apple documentation on KVO [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002307-BAJEAIEE) says a little bit more. [This thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/193787-with-what-does-apple-swizzle-the-isa-pointer-in-kvo.html) says a little bit more about the actual implementation of KVO and isa-swizzling.